# How to set alignment of individual x-axis labels in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart where basically I want to set the alignment of the first/last labels on the x-axis to be left/right and any labels in between would be the default center. From what I can tell there is only a way to set the Labels.alignment property to apply to all labels and no clear way to individually align them

here is a before and after pic of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

```
xAxis: {
        title: {
        enabled: false,
        text: ''
    },
    crosshair: {
        width: 2,
        color: '#C4C4C4',
        dashStyle: 'shortdot'
    },
    
    lineColor: 'transparent',
        tickLength: 1,
    labels: {
        //overflow: 'justify',
                step: 1,
                formatter: function() { 
       console.log(this.value)
                //if(this.value == 0 || this.value == 9)
                        return Highcharts.dateFormat("%b<br/>%Y", new Date(chartData.Dates[this.value]));
        },
        //align: 'center',
        style: {
            fontSize: '14px'
        }
    },

    //tickPositions: [0,3,5,7,9]
},
```

any help would be appreciated, here is my working fiddle:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6u4rmpnz/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the render callback to find those labels and use the translate feature to move them.

```
  chart: {
    height: 300,
    events: {
      render() {
        const xAxis = this.xAxis[0];
        const ticksPositions = xAxis.tickPositions;
        const ticks = xAxis.ticks;
        const firstTickLabel = ticks[0].label;
        const lastTickLabel = ticks[ticksPositions.length - 1].label;

        firstTickLabel.translate(firstTickLabel.getBBox().width / 2, 0)
        lastTickLabel.translate(-lastTickLabel.getBBox().width / 2, 0)
      }
    }
  },
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/krL5ey1o/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#translate

Comment: ok cool! This moves the label itself, but the text inside the labels are still center aligned. I am trying to left/right align the text as well for the first and last like in my pic